# Non ASCII character sended using Ajax cannot be decoded properly in Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, character-encoding

I am sending an AJAX request with jQuery post() and serialize. That uses UTF-8.
For example when 'ś' is a name input value , JavaScript shows `name=%C5%9B`. 
I have tried setting form encoding without success.

```
<form id="dyn_form" action="dyn_ajax.xml" style="display:none;" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

The same happens with `encodeURI(document.getElementById("name_id").value)`. I'm using Servlets on Tomcat 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of problem many times.
Verify your pages are saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really UTF-8, try `decodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

I always had a hard time convincing the request object to decode the URIEncoded strings correctly.

I finally made the following hack.

```
    try {
        String pvalue = req.getParameter(name);
        if (null != pvalue) {
            byte[] pbytes = pvalue.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            res = new String(pbytes, "UTF-8");
        }
    } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // This should never happen as ISO latin 1 and UTF-8 are always included in jvms.
    }
```

I don't really like this, and it's been a while since I stopped developing servlets, but it was already on tomcat 5.5, so it's worth trying.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this one time and accept answer. If it works, I will accept the answer.